# Boot from CD on Inspiron 7500

Tags: linux, boot, bios, dell-inspiron

I recently acquired an old Dell Inspiron 7500. It has Windows XP installed on it currently and is super slow. So I decided to install Linux on the machine, but I have failed over and over. I have tried Ubuntu, Crunchbang, Fedora, and Mint. It is set in BIOS to boot from CD/DVD first. I also put in a Windows Server 2003 disk and it wouldn't boot to that either. I then tried to update the BIOS, but I don't have nor know where to obtain floppy disks anymore. I did read somewhere that X has problems with this model due to display settings.

1. How can I install Linux?
2. If I can't install Linux how can I install Server 2003?
3. How can I update the BIOS?

Comment: So no matter what bootable disc you put in the drive, it won't boot to the disc?  When it boots into Windows, can you read any discs at all?  Is the problem the optical drive itself?  Does it even have a CD/DVD drive, or is it limited to only having a CD drive?

Comment: I ask these questions, because that model could have been shipped with a combo floppy/CD drive, and you could be attempting to boot to DVDs.

Comment: The disk drive says DVD Rom and it has a floppy drive under that. The boot sequence when a disk is in the tray is longer. Without a disk its POST splash screen then Windows XP. With a disk its POST splash screen then black screen for 2 minutes then (where I assume something fails) Windows XP).

Comment: When you put the disk in while in XP the disk loading cursor appears and you can hear the drive working. However clicking on D: displays the insert a disk prompt. If you right-click on the drive eject still works. Could it be that it can't read dvd -r?

Comment: Even if you put the WIndows Server 2003 DVD in, it still gives you the Insert Disc prompt when you try to access the DVD from within XP?  That sounds like the optical drive can't read any discs any more.  Not unheard of, especially considering the age of the unit.

Comment: I believe its cause they are DVD -r, I found a Ubuntu disk that came from canonical, so its probably a proper dvd rom and it will read it from with in the OS, but will not boot from it.

Comment: It still sounds as if the drive is the reason why it won't boot to DVD.  Can you boot to a bootable CD?

Comment: I havent tried that, but I will. Currently im using the option on the Ubuntu DVD to add to the boot menu if you have trouble booting to cd...so if this doesnt work i'll try a damn small linux cd.

Comment: That didn't work. I am currently burning windows 2000 to a cd and will try and boot from that. If that works ill try server 2003 from a cd. I would like a linux distro but none that I want will fit on a cd. With 2k or server 2003 I know I will run into a lot of driver issues. For internet I'm currently using a netgear wifi card.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3313/discussion-between-bizarrechaos-and-bon-gart)

Comment: why don't you boot from a USB device then?

Comment: That isn't even an option in the bios, I got it to but from a CD and got server 2003 installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of a DVD I booted to a Server 2003 CD, and it will boot to any Linux CD as well. After reading the documentation released with the bios I decided it was a necessary update.